# Консоль в оконном приложении

Tags: c#, консоль, окно

Каким образом в Visual Studio в окне приложения на C# можно создать консоль (для выполнения запросов)? Или можно только создать консоль поверх окна? Но тогда как?

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду консоль для установки пакетов Nuget например? Попробуйте `Ctrl` + `W` + `A`

Comment: В настройках проекта установите сборку как консольное. По поводу ввода  консоль можно найти в интернете.

Comment: @Birdy Нет, мне именно надо чтобы в одном из окон программы была консоль,  являлась его частью, в которой выполнялись определенные команды, которые прописаны уже в коде (разработчиком, которые можно выполнять пользователю)

Comment: Просто используйте обычный `TextBox`.

Comment: Я так понял вы хотите встроить интерпретатор c#? тогда копайте в сторону динамической компиляции https://habrahabr.ru/post/199266/

Answer (score -1):

Это должно помочь

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AllocConsole();
}

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool AllocConsole();
```